# java quicksort stack overflow

Tags: java, stack-overflow, quicksort

i am still a beginner and i am trying to write a quick sort code

here is my code

```
package algo_quicksort;

public class Algo_quicksort {

    public static int partition(int[]A,int p,int r){
        int x=A[p];
        int i=p+1;
        int temp;
        for(int j=p+1;j<r;j++){
            if(A[j]<x){//if A[j] is bigger than the pivot do nothing 
                temp=A[j];
                A[j]=A[i];
                A[i]=temp;
                i++;
            }
        }
        temp=A[p];
        A[p]=A[i-1];
        A[i-1]=temp;
        return i-1;
    }

    public static void quickSort(int[]A,int starPos,int length){
        if(length==1){
            return;
        }
        else{
         if(startPos<length){
        int pivot= partition(A,0,length);
       quickSort(A,startPos,pivot+1);

        quickSort(A, pivot+2,length); 

        }
    }}


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[]={6,5,4,3,2,1};
        System.out.println("A[] after quicksort is: ");

        quickSort(a,0, a.length);
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            System.out.print(a[i]+"  ");
        }
    }
}
```

i get a stack over flow exception in the recursive calls

i do not see why and i would appreciate any help i get ^_^

Comment: I suggest you find the simplest case where this happens and use you debugger to step through the code to see what it is doing and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many bugs in this program, here are a few that I found:

1. You don't use `starPos` in `quickSort()`
2. You don't use `length` (you use `A.length`) in `quickSort()`
3. The pivot "overlaying" issue that charles mentioned
4. In `partition()` you should switch places of the item that is `right` to the pivot and smaller with an item that is `left` to the pivot and is bigger - you don't do that.

and there's probably more.
You can see an implementation I did for quicksort in Ruby (it's easy to migrate it to Java) and compare to your implementation until you get it right - it's trickier than most people think!

http://alfasin.com/playing-with-ruby/

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read it carefully but in

```
quickSort(A,0,pivot+1);
quickSort(A, pivot,A.length-pivot);
```

you definitely over count the element A[pivot] in two branches of your recursive method